# jQuery set date in html input date

Tags: jquery, html

Can anyone please help me set this date, `09/25/2017`, in my HTML date input?

```
<input type="date" class="form-control Credit_limit" name="Credit_limit" id="form_control_1">
```

```php
$(".Credit_limit").val("<?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($Invoices[0]['Credit_limit'])) ?>");
```

Comment: Tried uncommenting the PHP code...?

Comment: Yes, I uncommented it thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Does it work now? Have you checked exaclty what the PHP code is outputting in to your JS?

Comment: What is the resulting PHP expression?

Comment: No it not working

Comment: @shahrushabh, show the rendered jQuery code please.

Comment: Do you echo the PHP to an external Jquery file? or is it inside <script> tags on your PHP file?